# В laravel 5.5 переход при ошибке валидации

Tags: php, laravel, route

Всем привет,
Тестируя REST API для создания юзера я создал небольшое меню по руту `/home`
с элементом “Create user”  и урлом `/testing_demo_user_update`
в обработчике которого чекрез `curl` вызываю `/register`

Вопрос в том что при ошибке валидации идет переход на `/home`, а не на `/testing_demo_user_update`,
хотя этот урл я прописал в `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/testing_demo_user_update';  // !!!!!!!!

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    use funcsTrait;

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $this->debToFile( ' RegisterController::validator:: $data::' . print_r( $data, true ), false );  // ЭТОТ КОД ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $this->debToFile( ' RegisterController:create:: $data::' . print_r( $data, true ), false );   // ЭТОТ КОД НЕ ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

А как правильно чтобы был возврат на `/testing_demo_user_update`?

Спасибо !

---

Я закоментарил в app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php
middleware('guest')

и проверил что в app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php код

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
       return redirect('/home');
}
```

не вызывается

Все равно есть переход на “/Home”  выводом на экран сообщения:

> Redirecting to “/home”

Порывшись в коде нашел, что переход выполняется через метод setTargetUrl в конструкторе класса RedirectResponse файле в файле vendor/symfony/http-foundation/RedirectResponse.php

В файлах моего проекта ссылок на RedirectResponse нет

Что может вызывать этот метод и как его убрать ?

---

По-прежнему ищу решения...
Порывшись в коде, нашел что есть определение класса RedirectResponse в файле
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php

Но вызывается класс vendor/symfony/http-foundation/RedirectResponse.php

Это можно где-то перепрописать?

Я вставлял в свои контролы и модель вызов

```
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
```

но безуспешно...

Answer (score 0):

Если закидывает в `/home`, то получается отрабатывает `middleware('guest')`, вот тут `/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` прописан редирект, вот

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
       return redirect('/home');
}
```

уберите `$this->middleware('guest');`, так как в случае ошибки, у вас пользователь не создается, и получается он не авторизован и его редиректит на `/home`